# Leibniz rule for double integral?

Tags: calculus

I have a probably rather simple question, but I'm afraid I can't find the solution myself, even though it probably exists alredy somewhere in this board. I'm sorry to waste your time.

$\frac{d}{dy} \int_y^a \int_z^a f(y,z) \;dy\; dz$

where a is some finite number.

Thank you very much for your help!

Vils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some abuse of notation here, insofar as the letter $y$ is used as integration variable in the inner integral and as independent variable for some "outer" function $h$. We are talking about 
$$h(y):=\int_y^a\int_z^a f(t,z)\>dt\>dz\ .$$
Let the inner integral be
$$g(z):=\int_z^af(t,z)\>dt\ .$$
Then 
$$h(y)=\int_y^a g(z)\>dz$$
and therefore
$$h'(y)=-g(y)=-\int_y^a f(t,y)\>dt\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

As written, the interior $y$ is irrelevant because is a bound variable:
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\int_y^a\int_z^a f(y,z)\,dy\,dz =
\frac{d}{dy}\int_y^a\int_z^a f(x,z)\,dx\,dz =
\frac{d}{dy}\int_a^y\int_a^z f(x,z)\,dx\,dz.
$$
and now, applying the FTC:
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\int_a^y\int_a^z f(x,z)\,dx\,dz =
\int_a^y f(x,y)\,dx.
$$